# Load SVG file with jQuery - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

In development it seemed to work well, I used to load the files like this:

```
$(".div").load("/assets/svg_file.svg");
```

But now that I have pushed the project to Heroku, it gave me a 404 error inside my console. It also happened with some images I included, but it was fixed by changing the default html image tag to this:

`<%= image_tag("logo.png") %>`

Since I can't include any ruby code on the client side, how do I do it?

Comment: did you try asset precompile?

Comment: try to access directly in URL or check your git status

Answer (score 0):

If any user faces the same issue, go to production.rb file (`config => environments => production.rb`) and change `config.assets.compile = false` to `config.assets.compile = true`. This should fix it.